# need to convert List output to a dictionary or preferable json. Please suggest

Tags: python

While Fetching the online trading data my output is coming like:-

```
['2019-02-10T00:17:00.000Z', 3629.0, 3629.5, 3629.0, 3629.5, 91920.0],
```

I want the output to be something like:-

```
[{"TimeStamp":"2019-02-10T00:17:00.000Z", "Open":"3629.0","Close": "3629.5", "Low":"High":"3629.0", "Low":"3629.5", "Volume":"91920.0"}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is import the json module and use json.dump(mList, file).

However, the structure you want, I believe it is best to parse your list into a dictionary and then serialize that dictionary to a json file with the json module. Basically, json.dump(mDict, file)

**Example:**

First import the json module.

```
import json
```

Then parse your list into a dictionary (there are different ways of doing this):

```
mList = ['2019-02-10T00:17:00.000Z', 3629.0, 3629.5, 3629.0, 3629.5, 91920.0]
mDict = {
    "TimeStamp":mList[0],
    "Open": mList[1],
    "Close": mList[2],
    "High" : mList[3],
    "Low" : mList[4],
    "Volume" : mList[5]
    }
```

Or you could also use the zip method by Jay.

Then finish with

```
with open('test.json','w') as my_json:
    json.dump(mDict,my_json)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a dupe of that (quite), since he's trying to convert a list to a json array of objects.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added a way of doing that now

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. In this, I am maintaining a list of keys in the same order as your input list and then using zip to pair them.

```
data = ['2019-02-10T00:17:00.000Z', 3629.0, 3629.5, 3629.0, 3629.5, 91920.0]

keys = ['TimeStamp', 'Open', 'Close', 'Low', 'High', 'Volume']

res_dict = {}
for x,y in zip(keys, data):
    res_dict[x] = y

res_list = [res_dict]
print res_list
```

Output:

```
[{'Volume': 91920.0, 'TimeStamp': '2019-02-10T00:17:00.000Z', 'High': 3629.5, 'Low': 3629.0, 'Close': 3629.5, 'Open': 3629.0}]
```